# duplicate views in monodevelop

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I'm having trouble working with the MonoDevelop IDE for the MonoTouch,
for example I cannot seem to find a good way to duplicate Controllers, if I just copy the .cs file together with its .designer.cs and .xib, it would not allow connecting the controls to the header (.h) file in xcode editor.
What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried closing XCode and reopening?  There is also a "Manual" button for "split view mode" (or "Butler mode", I call it) that sometimes becomes enabled in XCode, it should always just say "Automatic".

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the value in the `[Register ("Foo")]` attribute in the designer file for the new class?